# openCV C++ reduce objects/blobs to centroids

Tags: c++, opencv, centroid

### Task:

I try to write a method, that reduces the objects in a binary image to their centroids (meaning center of mass).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Parameters:

```
Mat *pMA_Out, Mat *pMA_In, int mode, int method, unsigned int thickness
```

### Body:

```
//Allocate contours
vector<vector<Point>> vvp_countours;

//Find countours
findContours(
            *pMA_In,
            vvp_countours,
            mode,
            method,
            Point(0, 0));

//Get the moments
vector<Moments> v_moments(vvp_countours.size());
for(int c = 0; c < vvp_countours.size(); c++)
    v_moments[c] = moments(vvp_countours[c], false);

//Get the mass centers
vector<Point2f> v_centroid(vvp_countours.size());
for(int c = 0; c < vvp_countours.size(); c++)
    v_centroid[c] = Point2f(
                v_moments[c].m10 / v_moments[c].m00,
                v_moments[c].m01 / v_moments[c].m00);

//Create output image
Mat MA_tmp = Mat(pMA_In->size(), CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));

//Draw centroids
for(int c = 0; c < v_centroid.size(); c++)
    line(
                MA_tmp,
                v_centroid[c],
                v_centroid[c],
                Scalar(255),
                thickness,
                8);
*pMA_Out = MA_tmp.clone();
```